I went or I had gone in this situation?
I've been trying to figure out for a while which tense I should use in this example, I would really appreciate it if you could help me, thank you!
"Do you remember when I told you that I went to 5 different book stores because i was looking for  a book?"
or
"Do you remember when I told you that I had gone to 5 different book stores because i was looking for  a book?"
I think the correct answer would be the Past Perfect, because It happened before the other action, but I am not sure.

Both are possible. The past perfect is unnecessary as the sentence clearly tells the listener that the going happened before the telling.
We don’t need to use the perfect unless it is necessary or worry about mastering it.

Do you remember when I told you that I went to five different book stores because I was looking for a book?


OK, i think i got it, thank you very much!

For the second variant, "I was looking for a book" would be also incorrect I guess, because the idea of looking for a book happened before the going. Is it correct?

It's fine. During the time that you were visiting the different shops, you were in the process of searching for the book. Obviously you must have had the idea first, but that doesn't need to be shown by the choice of tense.

“We should avoid using the perfect unless it is necessary”? Why do you say that? I know that some here on ELL counsel learners not to worry about learning to master it, that  they can get along okay without using it. But as a native speaker, I would definitely prefer it (and use it!) out of the pair of alternatives proposed by the OP.

Alright, fair, thanks.   I've edited paragraph 2.

A lot of learners overuse Perfect verb forms. I think it's because their teachers find it fairly easy to describe the main contexts where the Perfect can be used, but they neglect to point out that most native Anglophones don't very often use it unnecessarily. In particular, we tend to avoid repeating Perfect forms, or using them when the sequence of events is contextually obvious without including a Perfect form simply to indicate [something else] had happened before the primary past event referenced by this utterance. If we know it was before, had is superfluous.

@FumbleFingers, agreed.
